# AWS Cognito Import throw userNotFound

Tags: ios, xcode, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to migrate a batch of users into Cognito via a CSV (i.e. one-time import).  This part works successfully and I can see the users in the User Pool.  As expected, I see the user with a status of "Enabled / RESET_REQUIRED".  So far so good, right?

When I try to sign-in to the user in my mobile app, it throws an error of "userNotFound" instead of the "passwordResetRequired" which would trigger the proper flow.

Has anyone seen this?  Or know how to solve this problem?

Just for grins, here is my code:

```
private func signInWithAWS(email: String, password: String) -> Observable<AWSSignInResult> {
        Observable<AWSSignInResult>.create { observer in
            AWSMobileClient.default().signIn(
                username: email.lowercased(),
                password: password,
                completionHandler: { signInResult, error in
                    if let signInResult = signInResult {
                        switch signInResult.signInState {
                        case .signedIn:
                            observer.onNext(.success)
                            observer.onCompleted()
                        default:
                            observer.onCompleted()
                        }
                    } else if let error = error as? AWSMobileClientError {
                        if case AWSMobileClientError.userNotConfirmed = error {
                            observer.onNext(.unconfirmed)
                            observer.onCompleted()
                            return
                        } else if case AWSMobileClientError.passwordResetRequired = error {
                            observer.onNext(.resetPasswordRequired)
                            observer.onCompleted()
                        }
                        let message = getCognitoErrorMessage(error: error)
                        observer.onError(AuthServiceError.signIn(message))
                    }
                }
            )
            return Disposables.create()
        }
    }
```

It fails the "userNotConfirmed" and "passwordResetRequired" checks into the generic handler because the actual error is "userNotFound".